# how to make dotted leader in ToC be the same size and style, as title which it follows?

Tags: tocloft, leaders

Consider test case:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{3}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{2}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test1}
\section{Test1.1}
\section{Test1.2}
\chapter{Test2}
\end{document}
```

Changing in ToC size and style of *chapter* title and page number to `Large\bfseries` don't affect dotted leader, which remains `\normalfont`, as for *section*. And didn't find relative option in `tocloft` documentation. How to fix it?

Comment: How about`\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\Large\cftdotfill{3}}`?  Is this what you mean?

Comment: The proper solution is to include the font size and/boldness in the `\cftXleader` command. As Steven demonstrates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, that it is the font size of the dots needing to be changed, then perhaps this, `\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\Large\cftdotfill{3}}`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\Large\cftdotfill{3}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{2}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test1}
\section{Test1.1}
\section{Test1.2}
\chapter{Test2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, thank you. fix was so obvious